# CORS WebAPI and Web project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have views with angular in ASP.NET MVC Web project. And those angular scripts references to /api/mycontroller/method to get data. This "/api/mycontroller/" is in that same Web project.

Now I want to move those API to WebAPI project. And how to relate with that? 
That angular in Web should communicate to WebAPI project.

Both in the same solution.

Comment: remove your mvc controller and refer to the webapi controllers

Comment: most probably - `scheme://host:port` of your project + the route of api controllers

Comment: I don't want manualy change URL in Angular scripts every time when change enviroment. There are no other way?

Comment: Put it in a variable and change it only in one place?

Answer (score 0):

Publish your Web API project in a different URL, reference that URL instead of the current one within your angular application, and that should be all. The URL for each method will depend on the routes you define.

If your Web API is on a different host than the angular application, add this HTTP header into your angular web application's server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://webapihost.com
```

It should be easy to set up this header in any web server.
If you're using IIS 7+, modify your webconfig this way:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://webapihost.com" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Or [add the header into the server's configuration manually](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771148(v=ws.10).aspx)